# Why firebase is not sending notifications as expected?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to use firebase for sending notifications, I want to send it for IOS and Android but separately, the even if I do not include apns or android fields, it is still sending for both

I'm using nest js below

```
const serviceAccount: ServiceAccount = {
  clientEmail
  projectId
  privateKey
}
export type AdditionOptions = {
  forAndroid: boolean
  forIos: boolean
  forWebsite: boolean
}

const instance = admin.initializeApp(
  {
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  },
  'alrabiaamobile',
)

const fcm = {
  android: {
    notification: {
    sound: 'default',
  },
  priority: 'high',
} as AndroidConfig,
apns: {
  payload: {
    aps: {
      sound: 'default',
    },
  },
  headers: {
    'apns-priority': '5',
  },
} as ApnsConfig,
}

@Injectable()
export class MessagingService {
  notifyTopics(payload: TopicMessage, options?: AdditionOptions) {
    const both = !options
    return instance.messaging().send({
      ...payload,
      android: both ? fcm.android : options?.forAndroid ? fcm.android : undefined,
      apns: both ? fcm.apns : options?.forIos ? fcm.apns : undefined,
    })
  }
}
```

in the notifyTopics function we are sending android and apns, but even if I exclude apns, it is still sending for IOS, and vice versa for android